# Java using akka to publish commands to server

Tags: java, akka, event-bus

I'm new with akka, so want to ask how to add event to event bus and catch it called. There is code sample.

```
      localEventBus = new com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus(new ExceptionHandler());

            Object listener = new Object()
            {
                @Subscribe
                public void witingCommand(SomeCommand cmd)
                {
                    //Here I want to catch call
                }
            };
    ...
    localEventBus.register(listener);
    ...
      client = system.actorOf(Props.create(ClientActor.class, localEventBus, receptionists));
    ...     

     client.tell(new Publish(Constants.COMMAND, someCommand), noSender());
```

Types:

```
private final ActorSystem system;
private ActorRef client;
```

ClientActor.java

```
final class ClientActor extends UntypedActor
{
     ClientActor(final EventBus eventBus, final List<ActorSelection> receptionists)
    {
        localEventBus = eventBus;
        clusterReceptionists.addAll(receptionists);
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart()
    {...}

    @Override
    public void postStop()
    {...}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Object msg)
    {...}
}
```

Problem is that 'witingCommand' is not being called, maybe someone can tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: What's in your ClientActor?

Comment: extension for 'UntypedActor'

Comment: Once again, what's *in* your ClientActor?

Comment: Added class structure with main methods.